# Symfony the right way assets path

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to find out, how to get path of my css and js files.

This is my base.html.twig in app/Resources/views/base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It cant find my assets, because it is seeking in web/ directory by default. How should my path look like to find the files in app/Resources/views?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to include stylesheet as below :

```
{% stylesheets 'css/bootstrap.min.css' 
               'css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
filter='cssrewrite' %}
{% enstylesheets %}
```

Also you should install assets and you can use symlink option to assets:install command. This will make symlink in web folder to your bundle public folders

```
app/console assets:install --symlink
```

Without symlink option this task makes copy of files, so your changes doesn't affect.

You should also use assetic:dump command

```
app/console assetic:dump
```

**Clear the cache as well.**

Comment: it is not copying my assets from app/Resources/views to web/ directory

Comment: C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost>php app/console assets:install
Installing assets as hard copies.
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodi


It is installing some other assets which i dont have in app/Resources/

Comment: can you create chat please?

Comment: Required assets will be installed for the bundles as well. Whether your css and js assets installed or not?

Comment: my css and js are not in bundle, they are in app/Resources/views/css and app/Resources/views/css. The question is - i dont know the right path to load it in my base.html.twig which is also in app/Resources/views/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92660/discussion-between-tigran-muradyan-and-ankii-gangrade).